# Trying to start Google Play Services Games example

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I'm very new to Android studio, so this is probably a stupid question.

As of current I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

and got stuck at step 1 almost right off the bat. I downloaded the whole project as I'm trying to start and test "Typeanumber". Upon importing I went to "TypeaNumber" and changed the AndroidManifest.XML to a random domain. Quite obviously this didn't change anything. I still can't run the project and there're errors **everywhere**.

The XML looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pieps.testgame">


<application
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In the source, where I find the classes, there're like 5 directories that all seem exceptionally redundant. In the classes the wrong package is displayed as well.

Am I suppose to change **all** packages throghout the entire project(if so the documentation fails pretty hard)? What am I suppose to do to get this working?

Comment: You have mixed `com.google.example.games.tanc` and `com.pieps.testgame`... The later needs to be where your MainActivity should exist

Comment: If you are new to Android Studio, you're at the wrong getting started location. All Google play services apps assume you know how to use Android Studio / make an app

Comment: @cricket_007 I do know how to actually write apps. This doesn't exactly relate to my question. Also the documentation told me I had to change the package and you're now suggesting I change it back to the original(?)

Comment: I've not read the documentation. All I'm pointing out is that you've two mentioned packages in the manifest, which is likely one of the errors you've not mentioned here

Comment: @cricket_007 No offense but you aren't helping then. I referred to the specific part as well(step 1, which is literally 5/6 lines of text) and my problem with it.

Comment: I understand that, but what are the errors that you get, exactly? Yes, the instructions says change the application ID in the manifest (which also requires changing the Java code package and imports), and you'll want to edit the Gradle file to do the same

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. But now I cannot run it, and the configuration fails to find a module. Sigghhh

Comment: The `build.gradle` file is trying to compile a separate module project, yes